# How to store webpages automatically for viewing offline as fallback?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, raspberry-pi, offline-caching

I'm currently doing a project for showing a slideshow (build in HTML, CSS and JavaScript) on a television, using a Raspberry Pi. Now I would like the slideshow to be displayed even when the Raspberry is not connected to the internet. Does anyone have a solution or idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly...

What you will need to look into is ***service workers***!

**Important note**: They only work on **trusted** websites: Sites with **https** or on **localhost** (for testing purposes)

Here is a tutorial on offline support with service workers: https://css-tricks.com/serviceworker-for-offline/ But there are other great tutorials out there too!

Comment: Definitely worthy to take a look at it, thanks for the suggestion!